# RewriteRule for the categorry RSS feeds on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to add the sufix /rss2 to a default WordPress URL for an RSS feed.

I would like 
http://www.mydomain.com/blog/category/news/feed/ to go http://www.mydomain.com/blog/category/news/feed/rss2

In order to do this, I'm using this RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([^/])/feed/?$ http://www.mydomain.com/blog/category/$1/feed/rss2/ [NC,L]
```

But I cannot make it work. Somehow, WordPress rewriterules ignore mine.

I have my blog installed under the /blog directory and I tried to put this rule before and after the WordPress module in .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

[[[[I tried to put it here with no luck]]]]

RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

[[[[I tried to put it here too with no luck]]]]
```

Any ideas on how to do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The only way I see, to get it working, is to adding the proxy flag `[p]`

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVED] The problem was the RewriteRule, this is the correct one:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/category/(.*)/feed/?$ http://www.mydomain.com/blog/category/$1/rss2/ [L,R=301]
```